# How to make background image to be displayed fully and to cover the full size

Tags: html, css, background-image, contain, cover

I have a header div, which I want to be fully covered with a background image. I want the image to be fully shown, so nothing is cropped. However, it seems to be stretching the image and cropping it.

css:

```
..header{

        border-top-left-radius:5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        max-width: 600px;
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 200px;
        background: url("img/bg-abstract.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
        background-position: left top;
        background-size: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
background-size:cover
```

Comment: That doesn't cork, the image is zoomed into massively. With contain i come closer to the image than cover.

Comment: Well, so I don't understand what you need. Have you try with background-size: 100% 100%; ? I'm not sure this is what are you try to obtain.

Comment: I've tried that too - what I want is for an image of size lets say 40 x 40 to fit the size of my div, even when the div gets resized. So I want the picture to be fully displayed and to cover the background fully too. Does that make a bit more sense? Sorry for the miss communication.

Comment: What are you saying should work with background-size: 100% 100% because in this way the image will touch all the sides of the div,(obviously streching it if the image size is not equal to the div size). Don't worry, probably the problem about communication it's mine :) If you can post an image maybe we can understand better ;)

Comment: sorry for the late reply - basically the image scrolls with the main scroll. so at one point it is shown perfectly but at another point it only shows 10% of the image. i will try show you some pictures.

Comment: Unfortunatlly I can't add images at the moment. Sorry. Also, i have a logo image on top of the background image, that is positioned tothe bottom of the div. When I scroll the logo goes out of the div and the background image becomes smaller.

Answer (score -1):

`background-size: cover` Also try using `%` instead of `px`.